# Why can't I execute write command on all buffers with :bufdo?

Tags: buffers, save

I have multiple buffers open, some currently visible, some not. I know I can `write` all of them with `:wa`. However, I am curious, why `:bufdo w` does not work. When I try it in a buffer with unsaved changes, vim tells me

```
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
```

Why is this so?

Comment: I don't reproduce your error, can you try with `set hidden` ?

Comment: With `hidden` enabled it works.

Comment: My guess is, your current buffer is modified. And when doing :bufdo, Vim first tries to go to the first buffer, which isn't allowed, unless you set hidden or write the current buffer first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm feeling like you don't have the option `hidden` set.

Basically, it means that you cannot switch from an unwritten buffer to another one.

In your case you cannot save any buffer because it should change from an unwritten buffer. Adding the `hidden` option will fix this.

You can find more with : `:h hidden`.

Comment: I find it strange though. Since the operation I want to run is writing the buffer, I would expect that vim attempts to do that first, before switching to the next buffer.

Comment: You should really look at `:h hidden` ;) I quote "The commands that move through the buffer list sometimes make a buffer hidden although the 'hidden' option is off ..."

Comment: I read it, but I don't understand how it relates.

Comment: I think that when you enter `:bufdo w`, vim first switchs to the first buffer to write it, then, go to the second one and write it, and so on.. So your current buffer becomes hidden, which is forbidden without setting the `hidden` option.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable. Not sure if I'm the only one, but I rarely find it trivial to understand vim's documentation when it comes to non-obvious features.

Comment: @Nobe4 @oarfish In fact, if you do `:help bufdo` it shows that it works as `:bfirst` `:{cmd}` `:bnext` `{cmd}` etc. which confirms what you are seeing :-)

Comment: If you're finding the need to write all buffers, I'm guessing you're already using some `!`s in your edit / file navigation commands. It would be appropriate to follow that pattern, using `:bufdo! write`. However, for reasons unrelated to this problem, I'd still highly recommend setting `'hidden'`.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have modified buffers open in tabs or splits, but no actual modified hidden buffers. For that scenario, `:tabdo` and `:windo` could come in handy (and they can be combined!).